# Can not find "Create Pull Request" in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have tried to create pull request as written in WebStorm manual:

> To create a pull request:
>
> On the main menu, choose "VCS | Git | Create Pull Request". The Create Pull Request dialog box opens.

But it is not there.
What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

If you defined a remote to GitHub. It will appear on that menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the github plugin is installed and activated in Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) | Plugins | Installed (or install from marketplace tab). Also make sure there's an account in Version Control | Github.